# What does the FP2108T Ic do?

Tags: integrated-circuit, controller, tv

I have disassembled Parts of something (I think it was an old TV or RC controller).
There I found an IC with this printed on top of it: "Futaba Japan FP2108T 9175K". I am not good enough that i can understand the [circuit/datasheet](http://www.chinabaike.com/uploads/allimg/110428/235T55237-0.gif) so I want to ask you out of curiosity what it does. Its enough for me to get a rough Idea, of what its purpose is.

Comment: Look here: http://www.rcgroups.com/forums/showpost.php?s=75e8a8885a4361a419602384d7e709e1&p=8157330&postcount=6

Comment: Interesting circuit! The FP2108T only encodes 2 channels, but this circuit adds an extra channel externally (on/off only, controlled by switch K4) using a CD4011 quad NAND gate. So _that's_ how you do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Futaba is a known brand of consumer radio control equipment.

The schematic using the IC you linked to seems to indicate that it is a complete Radio control encoder and modulator.  It will 'measure' the joy-stick positions with potentiometers and provide some other features and then generate a baseband or encoded servo control sequence. If I had to guess from the schematic style (age) I would say a generic 2 (perhaps even 3-6) channel analogue PWM system.

Comment: You could try this image search to see if there are any other similar circuits that could give you additional hints on how it works or guide you to part numbers that may have data sheets available on the net.  -  https://www.google.com/search?q=radio+control+encoder+ic&tbm=isch